# devise wrongly routes site controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a problem with devise 1.1.5 on rails 3.0.3.
I have a controller "site" with an action "home". When I do a "rake routes" everything is as it should be, but when I click in my site on the sign_up link, it returns an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"devise/site"}
```

This is correct the controller should be "site", not "devise/site". 
This is in my routes.rb:

```
resources :articles

get "site/home"

get "site/about"

devise_for :users
```

But when I look with "rake routes" everything looks fine. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
articles GET    /articles(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
         POST   /articles(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
        PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
        DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
site_home GET    /site/home(.:format)           {:action=>"home", :controller=>"site"}
site_about GET    /site/about(.:format)          {:action=>"about", :controller=>"site"}
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                   PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                       PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                       DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
root        /(.:format)                    {:action=>"home", :controller=>"site"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the code for your sign up link?

Try changing your routes.rb to (I think the way 'home' and 'about' are currently describe might be causing the error):

```
devise_for :users
resources :sites do
  get :home, :on => :member
  get :about, :on => :member
end

resources :articles
```

also remember to set your root path so that when user does get signed-in they are directed to correct view.

Comment: This is the devise specific code: '<div id="user_nav">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>'
</code>

Comment: Sorry: This is the devise specific code: `<div id="user_nav">
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
    <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>`

Comment: please see changes to preious answer